# Failed to compile ./src/index.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in

Tags: reactjs, materialize, parallax

Because I cannot ask a question here due to some reputations thing someone came up with, this is the best way I found to actually get help. Check the image if you consider helping even if in a not so conventional way.

[image: This picture is the actual question]

it's legitimate and it's sad people go by a points system to offer help....

Comment: I suggest that you start a new project (create-react-app), check if it is working. Then, don't change the code yet, just install react-materialize. Check if it is working. Now, in the template code, import {Parallax} as you did, check again. Now try to use Parallax in the template code...

Comment: Yossi, thank you so much for your suggestion. I actually did that exactly and that's when my code broke. I will try to fix my own problem tonight, hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. My problem was that I did not initialize my bundle in my Public/index.html path. I'm sorry if this was a very obvious solution but I'm just learning React now and thought that "import" would do everything for me...

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering this same problem with an angular 6 app and the problem was that I had VS Code doing automatic import. VS code used this:

```
import {EventEmitter} from 'protractor'
```

instead of what I needed:

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

Moral of the story: check your import statements before panicking about compatibility issues.